# Best way to update large number of documents on a scheduled basis?

Tags: document-library, incoming-email

Currently we schedule a large number of excel and pdf reports to be emailed to different SharePoint libaries for our customers to consume.   We are starting to run into issues where certain reports don't get updated.  We re-run the job and they post.  I'm concerned we are hitting a limit of scale on how many files we are emailing SharePoint at a time.

Is emailing attachments the best way?  Or for large scale is it suggested we use another protocol for transfering files to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any limits to sending the emails to the SharePoint.

You mentioned that you have to re-run the job to upload the document  and when you re-run its works. So what is this program, is it in SharePoint or off sharepoint job. How that job triggered.

also how many servers in the farm and on how many you setup the SMTP?

did you check the smtp drop folder if message reached their when you said not updated?

What i am thinking, may be you job skip the document at the time of run because may be report not ready or still old.

Comment: The reporting tool we are using is Cognos. We have it email the user and Sharepoint library so we confirmed the report has run and been emailed from Cognos.   Unfortunately I don't have access to the back end as we are just a user of the tool so I dont have any specifics.   It was a more a general question of we are emailing 100-200 reports within an hour to a sharepoint library, is there a better way to do this that handles that scale, such as saving the file via a DAV mapping.  Thanks for your help